# POST list to django restapi

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to post a list of strings with some data but was unable to receive the list on server it gave me only last element of list

```
con = ["71qweq74520", "8324wqe57", "81ewqewq166"]
```

received

```
con = 81ewqewq166
```

code to receive at server API:-

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['POST'])
def getUser(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if isapiValid(request):
            for params in request.POST:
                print params,request.POST[params]
                #this prints last element of array/lis
```

python scirpt to post:-

```
con = ["71qweq74520", "8324wqe57", "81ewqewq166"] 
data = { 'apikey':apikey, 'sig':sig ,'con': con}
data2 = json.dumps(data)
#hostname = '127.0.0.1:8000'
hostname = 'XX.XX.XX.XX'
method = 'method'
task = 'getUser'
url = 'http://'+ hostname + '/' + method + task
r = requests.post(url, data=data)
#r = requests.post(url, data=data2) this too fails
```

How can i successfully get the posted list ??

Output from Httpd log:-

```
 [Wed Jan 27 13:35:05.868468 2016] [:error] [pid 18858] API validation passed
    [Wed Jan 27 13:35:05.868512 2016] [:error] [pid 18858] 81ewqewq166
    [Wed Jan 27 13:35:05.868547 2016] [:error] [pid 18858] one 99qwerty99
    [Wed Jan 27 13:35:05.868566 2016] [:error] [pid 18858] apikey 4618d76f2fb84eacbac3339e5c7f2b57
    [Wed Jan 27 13:35:05.868589 2016] [:error] [pid 18858] sig e8fe50c733ec6513c91f10caf63e7864
    [Wed Jan 27 13:35:05.868608 2016] [:error] [pid 18858] con  81ew
qewq166
```

Things recceived in request.post is :-

```
 {
            "_content_type": "application/json",
            "_content": "{\"one\": \"9998889999\",\"con\": [7106174520, 8324100257]}\r\n"
        }
```

But when i do request.POST.get('con') only last element is received ???

Comment: So you have an endpoint that goes like this `http:://localhost:8000/method/getUser` which is a post request. And it says method not supported on GET? Don't you think you should rename it? Also, try sending a 405 status code with not supported responses.

Comment: Also, you are probably receiving everything, try printing this `request.POST.get('con')` .

Comment: i tried printing that thats what gave me last element of list in request.POST.get('con')

Comment: I don't see you use it anywhere, post the output and full view here. Also, remove `'GET'` from the `api_view` decorator, this will handle the method not supported case, so you can remove the check for GET request in your code.

Comment: ok i added it and still no luck .....also i checked all the elements before adding this there was no list recevied .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is one of the funny things in Django. If you want to get a list from a post request you should use `request.POST.getlist(your_key)`. In your case `request.POST.getlist('con')`.

You can find more about this topic [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/1130).